# Localization testing on Android - Change Application or System locale

Tags: android, localization, locale, multilingual

I'm finally trying out some localization stuff on our application, and I've seem some posts regarding changing the application locale, and changing the System locale.

I've wondered if within the scope of our application, does it matters if I change the System locale or the application locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could notice, changing the application or the system Locale is not different with a side note that one would have to refresh the views.

I've wrote a [post](http://android-know-how-to.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/multi-language-android-application.html) about my experience with Multi-Languages... leave your comments at the bottom.